# axios post request to send image form data...data not being sent in the request.body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, input, axios

bellow is the code of my React component where I am trying to send formData from an image file to my backend api (node.js server) with axios. I manage to hit the backend route, however I am getting an undefined req.body... I am not sure how I would adjust the headers or some other property of the axios request to get access to this data.

```
function TestForm2() {

    const [file, setFile] = useState("");


    function handleFile(e) {
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        setFile(file)
    }

    async function handleUpload(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', file);

        axios({
            url: `${BASE_URL}/posts/api/upload`,
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
            },
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
          });

       


    }
      return (
        <div>
            <h1>Test Form 2</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
                <label for="image">Select File</label>
                <input type="file" 
                name="image" 
                onChange={handleFile} 
                className="form-input"/>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        )

}
```

backend route:

```
router.post('/api/upload', async function (req,res,next){
try {

    console.log(req.file)
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log("in the backend")
    res.json({msg: "WOO"})
    
} catch (e) {
    return next(e)
}
})
```

Just simple console.log's for now which is showing the req.body as an empty object {} and req.file as undefined. I suspect the formData is not being passed in in the correct form. Although I've added in  `` headers: {'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,} ``
the logged response is showing headers as

```
headers:
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Add the server-side code where you've used the said `req.body`

Comment: ok I've added it